# How to remove virtual CD/DVD-ROM

Tags: windows, powershell, cd-rom

On win10 we have possibility to mount iso files.
For each mounted iso system creates virtual CD/DVD-rom drive.
To see these drives we can use powershell:

```
PS C:\> gwmi win32_cdromdrive

Caption Drive Manufacturer VolumeName
------- ----- ------------ ----------
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM Volume{b62e0d58-541d-11e6-a1f7-005056873534} (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM Volume{d2c8b686-5410-11e6-a1f6-005056873534} (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM CdRom13 (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM CdRom14 (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM CdRom15 (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM CdRom16 (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM CdRom19 (Standard CD-ROM drives)
Microsoft Virtual DVD-ROM Volume{b62e1bc8-541d-11e6-a1f7-005056873534} (Standard CD-ROM drives)
NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 ATA Device D: (Standard CD-ROM drives)
```

Now my question is how to delete these devices using winapi/powershell whatever ?

I know that they are deleted when u dismount particular image using Dismount-DiskImage, but I would like to have "force" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$sh.Namespace(17).Items() | 
    Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "CD Drive" } | 
        foreach { $_.InvokeVerb("Eject") }
```

Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "CD Drive" } can you right click on iso drive what file system you see?

Comment: Works like a charm thx !
If anybody would like to trigger this action for particular driver 

     `$driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application`
     `$driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("E:").InvokeVerb("Eject")`

Comment: For those who fear that 17 is some index that could change, it is actually a constant of `ssfDRIVES = 0x11` thus safe to hardcode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants